# Find code where a method is being called in a loop with NDepend

Tags: c#, .net, ndepend

We have a large codebase with a lot of legacy code, sometimes not written in the most efficent form. I'd like to identify places where we can replace multiple Get method calls with a single MultiGet invocation. We currently use NDepend to analyze the code, but so far I have only managed to generate a list of places where the Get method is being used (using n. DepthOfIsUsing), which is not feasible to analyze manually.

How can I query for multiple uses of a specific method in a single method, either by appearing in source code multiple times or being invoked in a foreach or linq query? These scenarios should be identified:

```
// Scenario 1
var entities = entityIds.Select(_Factory.Get).ToArray();

// Scenario 2
var entityId1 = ...;
var entityId2 = ...;
var entity1 = _Factory.Get(entityId1);
var entity2 = _Factory.Get(entityId2);

// Scenario 3
var entityIds = ...;
foreach (var id in entityIds) {
   var entity = _Factory.Get(id):
   // do something
}
```

If this is not feasible with NDepend, which tools are able to perform this analysis?

Comment: Can someone explain the vote to close due to being off-topic? This seems like a "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" question to me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Jan, unofrtunatly by now NDepend cannot detect if a method is called in a loop or not, so this is not feasible